# converter sql para typeorm

Tags: sql, typeorm

Estou querendo converter esse código **sql** para **typeorm**, sem mais obrigado.

```
select * from Product join Category on  Category.id = Product.category_id where(Category.title = "Celular");
```

Comment: Como assim converter pra TypeORM?

Comment: fazer uma consulta nesse termo só que com orm typeorm.